# Backing up NAS - Bufallo Link Station 420 - Synology - Mac

Tags: mac, backup, nas, synology

I have a Bufallo Link Station 420. A few years old and it keeps dropping off the network. I see others with the NAS struggle with a similar problem so I'm just replacing it and have bought a Synology DS218 to replace it with. What's the best way to move 2TB of data across to the new NAS?

The backup utility on the Linkstation won't recognise the Synology. I have tried using Carbon Copy Cloner on my mac which is super slow (since data is going twice across the network via my mac) and of course before the backup really gets started the Linkstation disappears off the network.

So I'm thinking just to take one of the HDDs out of the Linkstation (set up as RAID 1). Would it work to remove 1 HDD and plug into mac pro (5,1) using SATA cable? Will it be readable?

Comment: Synology can mount remote folder using cifs/nfs.. so your Synology should be able to mount your LinkStation (LS) directly and then copy directly... assuming your LS will stay on the network long enough?

Comment: @Darius Tx yes tried this also and still have problem with LS dropping. Also I think the only way is to copy using "File Station" on the Synology and no way to do an incremental backup which would recognise the data already copied so I could do it in chunks when I get the LS dropping.

Comment: I don't know much about the Buffalo LS- but if it supports SSH, you can probably use `rsync` to sync data between the two? rsync supports incremental backup.